# How to calculate the prediction interval for an OLS multiple regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, least-squares, prediction-interval

What is the algebraic notation to calculate the prediction interval for multiple regression?

It sounds silly, but I am having trouble finding a clear algebraic notation of this.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Take a regression model with $N$ observations and $k$ regressors:
$$\mathbf{y=X\beta+u} \newcommand{\Var}{\rm Var}$$

Given a vector $\mathbf{x_0}$, the predicted value for that observation would be
$$E[y \vert \mathbf{x_0}]=\hat y_0 = \mathbf{x_0} \hat \beta.$$
A consistent estimator of the variance of this prediction is
$$\hat V_p=s^2 \cdot \mathbf{x_0} \cdot(\mathbf{X'X})^{-1}\mathbf{x'_0},$$ where $$s^2=\frac{\Sigma_{i=1}^{N} \hat u_i^2}{N-k}.$$
The forecast error for a particular $y_0$ is
$$\hat e=y_0-\hat y_0=\mathbf{x_0}\beta+u_0-\hat y_0.$$
The zero covariance between $u_0$ and $\hat \beta$ implies that
$$\Var[\hat e]=\Var[\hat y_0]+\Var[u_0],$$ and a consistent estimator of that is
$$\hat V_f=s^2 \cdot \mathbf{x_0} \cdot(\mathbf{X'X})^{-1}\mathbf{x'_0} + s^2.$$

The $1-\alpha$ $\rm confidence$ interval will be: $$y_0 \pm t_{1-\alpha/2}\cdot \sqrt{\hat V_{p}}.$$
The $1-\alpha$ $\rm prediction$ interval will be wider: $$y_0 \pm t_{1-\alpha/2}\cdot \sqrt{\hat V_{f}}.$$

Comment: The above answer is very well done, but I think [this source](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/315/) helps provide some context to the question.

Comment: @Dimitriy I believe your second eqn should have a carrot/hat, ‘^’, over the $\beta$.

Comment: Isn’t the forecast error the residual: $\hat{e}=\hat{u}$?

Comment: $\hat{e}$ is an estimation of $u_0$.

Comment: This should be the variance conditional on $x$, right?

Comment: What is the point of subtracting $k$ from $N$ in $s^2=\frac{\Sigma_{i=1}^{N} \hat u_i^2}{N-k}$?

Comment: @user398843 It the standard degrees of freedom correction, like dividing by n-1 for the standard error of the mean.