# Plus/Minus Model accuracy from $R^2$

Tags: regression, r-squared, prediction-interval

I completed a linear regression for a model I was working on, and obtained that the $R^2$ value was $R^2 = 0.801$.

Can one assess a $\pm$ error from this value for future predictions? I.e., if I now use this linear model to predict against a new set of data, can I use this $R^2$ value to get a  $\pm$ value on that prediction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't, for two reasons.

- [$R^2$ indicates the proportion of variance explained by your model.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) $R^2=0.80$ can mean that you explain 80% of *very little* variance, so your [prediction-interval](/questions/tagged/prediction-interval) (PI) should be small. Or it can mean that you explain 80% of *a huge lot* of variance, so your PIs should be large.
- $R^2$ is an in-sample measure of model fit. In-sample fits are very misleading as guides to out-of-sample predictive accuracy.

To calculate PIs for multiple regression, take a look at this earlier thread: [How to calculate the prediction interval for an OLS multiple regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/147242/1352)

Answer (score 4):

You are talking about Root Mean Squared Error of Prediction (RMSEP).

It is fundamentally different than the $R^2$ value, and they are not related in the way you are hoping.  Your $R^2$ value is the *approximate* amount of $y$-variance (dependent variable variance) explained by your $x$-matrix of covariates (independent variables).  This is answering the question *"how much variance can I explain with my given set of predictors?"*

Your RMSEP ([explained in this website on calibration](http://www.chemometry.com/Research/MVC.html)) is the approximate error that your model will produce in predicting a future out-of-sample value.  It is a metric used to answer *"if I use my current model in the real-world, how much error will it produce while predicting?"*

$R^2$ is used to determine how much variance a model explains.  RMSEP is used to determine how well your model can predict out-of-sample values.  They are not related.